# Operads are to multicategories as what are to polycategories

Tags: category-theory, operads

I have been reading a little about operads and their cousins multicategories.  I am wondering what the cousins to polycategories are and why these mysterious cousins aren't popular in literature.

Also, how are symmetric monoidal categories related to polycategories?

Comment: Well, a polycategory with one object. This would be an algebraic structure with both operations and co-operations.

Answer (score 2):

Operads are to multicategories (a.k.a. colored operads) what polycategories with one object are to polycategories. There is no special name for polycategories with one object that I'm aware of.

They encode "bialgebras" consisting of one object and multiple operations and cooperations (each with multiple inputs/outputs), whereas general polycategories encode bialgebras consisting of multiple objects and multiple operations and cooperations between them. They're not much more mysterious than polycategories.

These differ from the better-known PROPs in the shape of possible compositions (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1352515/10014)): suppose you have two morphisms $f : a \to (b,b)$ and $g : (b,b) \to c$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ are colors (objects). In a PROP you can plug both outputs of $f$ to the inputs of $g$ to get $g \circ f : a \to c$, wheras in a polycategory you can only plug one of the outputs of $f$ to one of the input of $g$ to get $g \circ_{i,j} f : a \to (b,c)$ (or $(c,b)$).

Comment: I wonder if properads or dioperads (both mentioned on the ncatlab page for [PROP](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/PROP)) are the right notion for this? (i.e. equivalent to polycategories with one object) I don't know enough the subject to say at the moment, but hopefully someone will be able to comment.

Comment: It seems like properad should be the right notion extending operads to something with multiple outputs, but I'm still not aware of a reference that they are the same thing as a polycategory with a single object. From tthe ncat page on properads:

"The idea is that operations in a properad can have multiple inputs and outputs, as opposed to a single output in an operad."

Comment: @Sintrastes Properads are also different things. Properads are basically what you get when you restrict PROPs to compositions where the graph is connected. I had forgotten about dioperads, it's possible that it's the same thing... I would need to check.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments to another answer, the word "dioperad" is also used for a one-object (symmetric) polycategory, although the communities of people who talk about dioperads and polycategories are so disjoint that hardly anyone seems to have heard of both of them.  See [this question and answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272308/dioperads-vs-polycategories).

The thing that's related to a polycategory in the same way that a monoidal category is related to a multicategory is a [linearly distributive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linearly+distributive+category), or perhaps a [star-autonomous category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/star-autonomous+category) depending on how much structure you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

According to Craig Antonio Pastro's [thesis](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~robin/Theses/pastro.pdf), the term you are looking for is *polyad*:

> We may describe morphisms in a one-object polycategory (or polyad) using pairs consisting of labelled cyclic graphs and their related signatures, up to renaming of nodes

(from page 19 of his thesis)